# how can i change the url of an existing page on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, web, url, location

I want the same page to open but with another url for example;

```
<li><a href="@(Utils.getKullaniciKayit()==null?Url.Action("Login","Home",new {Area="Kayit"}):Url.Action("Ekle","Randevu",new {Area="Kayit"}))" id="randevualUrl"  onclick="changeRandevuUrl();">@("RANDEVU AL".ToGecerliDileCevir())</a></li>
```

this href is as follows: /Kayit/tr/Home/Login
I want it to open with the following url:
/RandevuAl an appointment shaped